# Print Vector made up for structures in C++

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I'm trying to print out elements of a vector that is made up of structures. Here is the definition of the vector and its contents:

```
struct H_Data{
    double count[2];
    double min, max;
    list <double> Ref_Data;
};

struct Histogram
 {
    std::vector<H_Data> H;
}Hist[MAX_DIM];
```

Now I created a vector H and I want to print out all of its contents. I tried doing this with a for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<H.size();i++){
    cout << H[i] << endl;
}
```

But I get a type error here.

```
./CD.h:155:14: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka
  'basic_ostream<char>') and 'value_type' (aka 'H_Data'))
    cout << H[i] << endl;
```

Any help on how to print the contents?

Comment: By what magic is the compiler supposed to know how to print a `H_Data`?

Comment: Do some research about *operator overloading* and especially how to overload `operator<<`.